# How to generate text gradient with snap.svg or svg.js

Tags: gradient, snap.svg, svg.js

I have this svg

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 462 40" height="40" width="462" id="lol-text-1" class="lol-text__svg">
<desc>Created with Snap</desc>
<defs>
    <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0.3" x2="0" y2="0.8" id="Sikjr46ql1nr">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#cbac62"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#66481f"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="Sikjr46ql1nz">
        <text x="0" y="35" class="lol-text__mask" style="" fill="#ffffff">Pentakill</text>
    </mask>
</defs>
<g style="" mask="url('#Sikjr46ql1nz')">
    <text x="0" y="35" class="lol-text__shadow" style="" fill="#ad986a">Pentakill</text>
    <text x="1" y="36" class="lol-text__text" style="" fill="url('#Sikjr46ql1nr')">Pentakill</text>
</g>
```

As it says in the svg code, it was created with snap.
Here is the html tag used to generate the svg:

```
<span class="lol-text" style="display: none;">Pentakill</span>
```

I asume that the `style="display: none;"` was inserted after the svg was generated.

What i need is an example on how do i generate the same svg from an html tag using snap.svg or svg.js

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched a lot to find what I wanted and I found exactly what I was looking for.

Here is the code and an example: [text gradient generated with snap.svg](https://goo.gl/wj5KLa)

Answer (score 1):

[Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) will help you generate graphics, but it can also work with existing SVG. This means that your SVG content does not necessarily have to be created with [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/), you're also free to manipulate graphics created with tools like Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, or Sketch.

[Here](http://snapsvg.io/demos/) are some examples, which you can also find on the Demo section of their website.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sample snapsvg</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.2.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function()
   {
     var snap = Snap(912,912);
     var headline = snap.paper.text(56,100, ['The Three Layers','of','Every Web Page']).attr({fill: '#FBAF3F', fontFamily: 'Impact'}); 
   }
  </body>
  </html>
```

here you can see the [output](https://jsfiddle.net/RenjithVR4/mL234k1a/)

> **UPDATE**

if you want to know more about it with example.

http://www.sitepoint.com/create-infographic-using-snap-svg/

Comment: if you look here [link](http://promo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/music-of-league/) every `h3` tag has a svg in that i guess is generated automatically somehow and every svg has an unique random id that i`m sure was not inserted manually. I want to do the exact same thing on my site too without having to manually edit every id to be unique.

Comment: sorry,i don't understand you.

Comment: If you search for "snap" in this js file [link](http://promo.na.leagueoflegends.com/assets/music-of-league/dist/production.min.js) you will find lots of snap words and even "Created with Snap" and if you search for "lol-text" you will find at the bottom of the js file the part of the code used to generate the svg. I don't know javascript, I only know how to modify some easy stuff from a js file and the file from the link being minified I realy don't understand nothing.

Comment: this will give some basic ideas then.

Comment: I use joomla as a cms to post articles and to copy/paste the svg code every time I use a h2 or h3 tag is not helping. What I want to know is how do I achieve the exact same svg that i posted above. And I'm sure that the one who made this page [link](http://promo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/music-of-league/) didn't insert the svg there manually.How do i achieve that?